# Drag and Drop in primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces

I need to create two fieldsets that contain panels i need to drag and drop the panels from the first fieldset to the second one and the the reverse (from the second fieldset to the first one), So can the  component be  draggble and a droppable at the same time?

Comment: i'm reading about it now i didn't try it cause i'm new to primefaces

Comment: @user1657164 Maybe you should start by looking at the PrimeFaces showcase (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) and reading the documentation (http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).